# Homotopy group of 2-skeleton

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X=T^n$ be an $n$-torus and consider $X^{(2)}$ its $2$-skeleton. I know that $\pi_1(X^{(2)})= \pi_1(X)= \mathbb{Z}^n$, but which are the other homotopy groups of $X^{(2)}?$ I guess that $\pi_n(X^{(2)})=1$ for $n\geq 3$, but what about $\pi_2$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the $2$ skeleton of this space seems to be a wedge sum of $n$ choose $2$ $2$-tori. You can pass to the universal cover of this space, which is an infinite wedge of $R^2$s connected at their base points. This seems contractible, so I think that all these homotopy groups are trivial.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger: I thought so too, but it has the wrong fundamental group. For example, the fundamental group of the $2$-skeleton of $T^3$ is $\mathbb{Z}^3$, but the fundamental group of a wedge of three $2$-tori is $\mathbb{Z}^2\ast\mathbb{Z}^2\ast\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks! My mistake was obvious as soon as I read that. The 1- skeleton is a wedge of circles, the 2- skeleton slightly more complicated. I am going to think on whether or not my idea can be salvaged.